# how to access parameters from url in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2

In cook book of cakephp 3. It is given to build url using

```
echo $this->Url->build([
    "controller" => "Posts",
    "action" => "view",
    "foo" => "bar"
]);
```

which will output as

```
/posts/view/foo:bar
```

How to access the `foo:bar` in action and save in a variable `$foo` ?

Comment: are you sure you are using cake3? cake 3 would return `/posts/view/?foo=bar`. Seems a cake2 application

Comment: `$var = $this->request->param('foo')`

Comment: @arilia check this [http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html#generating-urls](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html#generating-urls)

Comment: I guess is an error in the documentation or maybe the recently changed it. Did you try your code? I just tried your exact code in a cake3.2.13 application and it gives `/posts/view/?foo=bar` as expected. Anyway @JacekBBudzyñski comment is correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there's an error in the cookbook, so I opened [**this**](https://github.com/cakephp/docs/issues/4229#issuecomment-237608815) ticket

if you use this code

```
echo $this->Url->build([
    "controller" => "Posts",
    "action" => "view",
    "foo" => "bar"
]);
```

you'll get an url like this

```
/posts/view/?foo=bar
```

the manual [**here**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#query-string-parameters) explains how to access the GET parameters

you can do

```
$this->request->query('foo');
```

or

```
 $this->request->query['foo'];
```

the first is null safe, it means that if the '`foo`' parameter is not set you simply get `null` and not an error

**Edit**

after 3.4.0 the new syntax is

```
$this->request->getQuery('foo');
```

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3.* version can use request Query :

```
$this->request->getQuery('utm_source')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in one line to get all the params as an Array:

```
$params = $this->request->getQueryParams();
```